# How to match " in Regular expression using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match `"` inside a string but I am not able to add `"` to the list

Current my regular expression is

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"[\\/:*?<>|]","", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I also want to add `"`

`\"` is not accepted.

Comment: What's about putting     \" into the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `"` to `""`.

Use `""` with verbatim strings..

i.e `@"[\\/:*?<>|""]"`

**OR**

Just use `\"` **without** verbatim strings.

i.e `"[\\/:*?<>|\"]"`

---

A character that is preceded with forward slash `\` is treated as a `special character`..

For example.. `\t`,`\n`,`\r` are special characters..

But `\e` is not a special character since `e` has no special meaning..So,compiler would show you compile time error `Unrecognized escape sequence`

In order to treat characters preceded by `\` literally(i.e to make it non special character) we use verbatim string i.e `@""`

Answer (score 1):

You must use \ to escape it.

For example: `\"`